# Regarding the vertical scrollbar using a read more button

Tags: html, css

Suppose ,we have given a list of 10 names , then initially 3 names are on the screen, then by clicking on the read more button then next 3 names appear till the end in html . Please tell me the code or some help so that I can add that in my code?

Comment: I have added only scrollbar and I have fixed the size of width and height and scroll , i have done auto , if it wexceeds then it scrolls but i want a button , so that clicking on that it shows the new names . <div class="slide"style=" width:1308px; height: 30px; overflow:auto;">

Answer (score 0):

You can take reference from below link

http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/loading-more-results-from-database